# Assert a specific and unique value in column

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate

my RDBMS is PostgreSQL. I am using SpringBoot and Hibernate as JPA.

Let's consider a very simple one-column table:

```
Man
    Age: integer
```

And I would like to implement a such method that add a man to the table. That method should satisfy the following condition:

```
At most one man in table can be 80 years old
```

.

```
@Transactional
void addMan(int age){
....
}
```

It looks like I need to take a exclusive lock for whole table, yes? How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a second solution.

Use `SERIALIZABLE` transactions that look like this:

```
START TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

SELECT count(*) FROM man WHERE age = 80;
```

Now, if the result is 0, continue:

```
INSERT INTO man VALUES (80);

COMMIT;
```

If two transactions try to do this concurrently, one will fail with a serialization error.

In that case, you just have to retry the transaction until it succeeds.

Serializable transactions perform worse than transactions with a lower isolation level, but they will still perform better than actually serializing the transactions.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a [unique constraint / index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-unique.html) to the table and let the database do the work.

```
create unique index man_age_unique_idx on man (age);
```

If a record with that age does not already exist, no problem.

If it does exist, you should get back a `PersistenceException` where the cause is a Hibernate `ConstraintViolationException`. From that you can get the name of the constraint that was violated, e.g. `man_age_unique_idx` in the example above.

```
try {
    entityManager.persist(man);
} catch (PersistenceException e) {
    if (e.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
        ConstraintViolationException cve = (ConstraintViolationException) e.getCause();
        if (Objects.equals(cve.getConstraintName(), "man_age_unique_idx")) {
            // handle as appropriate... e.g. throw some custom business exception
            throw new DuplicateAgeException("Duplicate age: " + man.getAge(), e);
        }
    } else {
        // handle other causes ...
    }
}
```